# Как Hibernate хранит cash 1-го уровня если Session одноразовая?

Tags: hibernate

Кешировние 1-го уровня связано с сессией. Но как такое кеширование может работать если при каждом обращении к DAO слою принято открывать новую сессию?

Пример:

```
public class DAO {

    private final SessionFactory factory;

    public User getUser(final String login, final String password) {

        try (final Session session = factory.openSession()) {

            final List<User> select = session
                    .createQuery(GET_USER_BY_LOG_PASS.val, User.class)
                    .setParameter("login", login)
                    .setParameter("password", password)
                    .list();

            return select.isEmpty() ? new User() : select.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Если я вызову метод `getUser` два раза с одинаковыми параметрами на одном объекте `DAO` то очевидно будет создано 2 разные сессии.

```
DAO dao = new DAO();
dao.getUser("test", "test");
dao.getUser("test", "test");
```

Озночает ли это что кэши 1-го уровня этих сессий будут согласованы или нет, вместе с закрытием сессии все данные кеша становятся мусором?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кэш первого уровня принадлежит сессии. У каждой сессии свой кеш. Вместе с закрытием сессии кэш очищается.

Содержимое кэша можете посмотреть с помощью [утилиты](http://konopkomikl.ru/2017/06/20/hibernate-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-first-level-persistence-context-cache/)

Comment: получается что что бы пользоваться преимуществами кеширования нужно оставлять сессию открытой?

Comment: Основное назначение кэша первого уровня - обеспечение персистности

Comment: а что в данном контексте понимается под персистентностью? Persistent я так понимаю что состаяние сущьности которая связана с открытой сессией. А что означает персистентность в контексте кеша?

Comment: Персистность - это некое свойство ПО, которое может быть реализовано в самом ПО или с привлечением стороннего ПО (например HIBERNATE). Суть персистности в том, что можно сделать load и данные загрузятся из БД, поработать, а потом сделать save и измененные данные сохранятся в БД,

Comment: получатся что в случае с БД персистентность и  работоспособность это синонимы... Наверно персистентность выделяет некоторые конкретные моменты в работоспособности..? А то получется база пишет и читает значит персистенто нет - не персистентно.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к вышесказанному.

Кеш первого уровня всегда включен по умолчанию и всегда он относится к сессии. Главная цель это уменьшить количество SQL запросов, которые выполняются в рамках транзакции. Вместо того, чтобы создавать по запросу на каждое изменение благодаря использованию сессии все будет выполнено по завершению транзакции.

Таким образом получается, что если мы в рамках сессии изменили сначала `User.name` и затем `User.surname`. То до тех пор пока сессия не закончится (или мы специально не вызовем метод flush()) эти изменения будут хранится только в кеше первого уровня. И в результате таких изменений у нас будет только один update запрос, содержащий оба измененных поля.

First level cache может быть полезен, когда у нас идет сложная бизнес логика в каком-либо методе. Например у нас идет последовательный вызов нескольких различных сервисных (бизнес) слоев:

```
public void updateConractData(Contract data) {

    customersService.update(data);
    employeesService.update(data);

}
```

При этом в каждом из этих сервисов у нас был запрос на проверку прав

```
    "SELECT * from Users WHERE user_id = :id"
```

Соответвенно в этих двух методах у нас будет только один физический запрос в БД.

**Но все это довольно специфично и надо рассматривать каждый конкретный случай отдельно!**